# How to change date format in google spreadsheet bar plot

Tags: google-sheets

I am very new to using google spreadsheet and trying to create a simple bar chart.

When I used the default plot I got x-axis labels in the format "%d/%m/%Y", I would like to change it to something like "Jan 1", "Jan 5", etc. How to do so?

I have shared public google sheet "barchartDate" here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10NzbtJhQj4hQBnZXcmwise3bLBIAWrE0qwSus_bz7a0/edit#gid=337388679

## Required

- My current x-axix labels are like "01/01/2016", I would like to change them to like "Jan 1 2016" and so on.

I have also looked at similar questions and was unable to find the answer myself

- [Google SpreadSheet Custom Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022056/google-spreadsheet-custom-date-format)
- [Google spreadsheet to Google Calendar format date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475932/google-spreadsheet-to-google-calendar-format-date)

Comment: Seems you need to create a [helper column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/142274/how-do-i-format-the-horizontal-axis-labels-on-a-google-sheets-scatter-plot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change to custom format by the following steps :)

[image]

My is in foreign language, but it says "Custom date and time format".
I remove the "/" delimiter and change the format of the month (Månad), by pressing the arrows and choose "Månad (Aug)". I also removed the prevailing zeros by clicking on the "Dag (05)" and change that format too.

[image]

Result then go from 1/1/2016 -> Jan 1 2016.

[image]